# Cannot resolve symbol NotNull with Slick 3.1.1

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I have a schema definition as follows:
package model

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json}
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.lifted.Tag

case class ApiKey(id: Option[Int] = None, key: String, createdAt: Timestamp)

object ApiKeys {

  implicit lazy val apiKeyFormat: Format[ApiKey] = Json.format[ApiKey]

}

class ApiKeys(tag: Tag) extends Table[ApiKey](tag, "api_key"){
...
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("createdAt", O.NotNull)
...
}
```

the compiler complains that `Cannot resolve symbol NotNull` even though the docs states that this option should be available: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html

Even if I look into the source there is not such thing. What am I missing in the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`O.NotNull` is removed in the latest version of the slick. By default everything is `not null` in slick when column is declared like this `column[A]`. To make the column `nullable` you have to declare it as `column[Option[A]]`